# Why doesn't gcc handle volatile register?

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization, volatile, avr, cpu-registers

I'm working on a timing loop for the AVR platform where I'm counting down a single byte inside an ISR. Since this task is a primary function of my program, I'd like to permanently reserve a processor register so that the ISR doesn't have to hit a memory barrier when its usual code path is decrement, compare to zero, and `reti`.

[The avr-libc docs](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_regbind) show how to bind a variable to a register, and I got that working without a problem. However, since this variable is shared between the main program (for starting the timer countdown) and the ISR (for actually counting and signaling completion), it should also be `volatile` to ensure that the compiler doesn't do anything too clever in optimizing it.

In this context (reserving a register across an entire monolithic build), the combination `volatile register` makes sense to me semantically, as "permanently store this variable in register `rX`, but don't optimize away checks because the register might be modified externally". GCC doesn't like this, however, and [emits a warning](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34351) that it might go ahead and optimize away the variable access anyway.

The bug history of this combination in GCC suggests that the compiler team is simply unwilling to consider the type of scenario I'm describing and thinks it's pointless to provide for it. Am I missing some fundamental reason why the `volatile register` approach is in itself a Bad Idea, or is this a case that makes semantic sense but that the compiler team just isn't interested in handling?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use a normal HW timer?

Comment: I am using a normal HW timer. The low-power timer on the AVR overflows after 32.768ms on the lowest-speed setting (internal 8MHz system clock, prescaler at 1024, 8 bits wide), and the standard way to extend that time is to use a countdown ISR.

Answer (score 5):

The semantics of `volatile` are *not* exactly as you describe "don't optimize away checks because the register might be modified externally" but are actually more narrow: Try to think of it as "don't cache the variable's value *from RAM* in a *register*".

Seen this way, it does not make any sense to declare a register as `volatile` because the register itself cannot be 'cached' and therefore cannot possibly be inconsistent with the variable's 'actual' value.

The fact that read accesses to volatile variables are usually *not* optimzed away is merely a side effect of the above semantics, but it's *not* guaranteed.

<strike>I think GCC should assume by default that a value in a register is 'like volatile' but I have not verified that it actually does so.</strike>

Edit:

I just did a small test and found:

1. avr-gcc 4.6.2 does *not* treat global register variables like volatiles with respect to read accesses, and
2. the Naggy extension for Atmel Studio detects an error in my code: "global register variables are not supported".

Assuming that global register variables are actually considered "unsupported" I am not surprised that gcc treats them just like *local* variables, with the known implications.

My test code looks like this:

```
uint8_t var;

volatile uint8_t volVar;

register uint8_t regVar asm("r13");

#define NOP asm volatile ("nop\r\n":::)

int main(void)
{
    var = 1; // <-- kept
    if ( var == 0 ) {
        NOP; // <-- optimized away, var is not volatile
    }

    volVar = 1; // <-- kept
    if ( volVar == 0 ) {
        NOP; // <-- kept, volVar *is* volatile
    }

    regVar = 1; // <-- optimized away, regVar is treated like a local variable
    if ( regVar == 0 ) {
        NOP; // <-- optimized away consequently
    }

    for(;;){}
}
```

Comment: I have confirmed by disassembly that GCC does not treat register variables in the sane way: Register variables accessed from C code are first copied to another register, then manipulated, then written back if necessary. Global register variables are not unsupported as far as I can tell.

Comment: Regarding interpreting `volatile` as "just don't cache the variable in a register": The spec specifically says that all accesses to `volatile`s must correspond exactly to the abstract state machine, in which "all expressions are evaluated" (5.2.1.3.3). Optimizing away evaluations, such as by eliminating loop tests, breaks this correspondence. Accesses can only be optimized away if the results of the evaluation wouldn't affect the abstract state machine.

Comment: @chrylis Which optimization level did you use for your test? My setup was with `-O2`, whereas `-O0` for instance is quite likely to not optimize away *anything*. - And yes, GCC itself did not complain about my global (or even global volatile) register variable. Yet, Naggy somehow comes to the conclusion that these declarations are erroneous for the quoted reason, and the disassembly kind of confirmed that at least they don't work as one might expect.

Comment: I'm using `-Os`. After seeing the code GCC came up with for `var--` (`push r24; mov r24, r3; subi r24,1; mov r3,r24; pop r24` instead of `dec r3`), I'm going to be doing anything speed-critical in assembly. And GCC has a specific warning (`-Wvolatile-register-var`) for this perfectly cromulent declaration. I just hoped to avoid inline assembly for ISR-flag-variable reads in my main loop.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you would use the `volatile` keyword on AVR variables is to, as you said, avoid the compiler optimizing access to the variable. The question now is, how does this happen though?

A variable has two places it can reside. Either in the general purpose register file or in some location in RAM. Consider the case where the variable resides in RAM. To access the latest value of the variable, the compiler loads the variable from RAM, using some form of the `ld` instruction, say `lds r16, 0x000f`. In this case, the variable was stored in RAM location `0x000f` and the program made a copy of this variable in `r16`. Now, here is where things get interesting if interrupts are enabled. Say that after loading the variable, the following occurs `inc r16`, then an interrupt triggers and its corresponding ISR is run. Within the ISR, the variable is also used. There is a problem, however. The variable exists in two different versions, one in RAM and one in `r16`. Ideally, the compiler should use the version in `r16`, but this one is not guaranteed to exist, so it loads it from RAM instead, and now, the code does not operate as needed. Enter then the `volatile` keyword. The variable is still stored in RAM, however, the compiler must ensure that the variable is updated in RAM before anything else happens, thus the following assembly may be generated:

```
cli
lds r16, 0x000f
inc r16
sei
sts 0x000f, r16
```

First, interrupts are disabled. Then, the the variable is loaded into r16. The variable is increased, interrupts are enabled and then the variable is stored. It may appear confusing for the global interrupt flag to be enabled before the variable is stored back in RAM, but from the instruction set manual:

> The instruction following SEI will be executed before any pending interrupts.

This means that the `sts` instruction will be executed before any interrupts trigger again, and that the interrupts are disabled for the minimum amount of time possible.

Consider now the case where the variable is bound to a register. Any operations done on the variable are done directly on the register. These operations, unlike operations done to a variable in RAM, can be considered atomic, as there is no read -> modify -> write cycle to speak of. If an interrupt triggers after the variable is updated, it will get the new value of the variable, since it will read the variable from the register it was bound to.

Also, since the variable is bound to a register, any test instructions will utilize the register itself and will not be optimized away on the grounds the compiler may have a "hunch" it is a static value, given that registers by their very nature are volatile.

Now, from experience, when using interrupts in AVR, I have sometimes noticed that the global volatile variables never hit RAM. The compiler kept them on the registers all the time, bypassing the read -> modify -> write cycle alltogether. This was due, however, to compiler optimizations, and it should not be relied on. Different compilers are free to generate different assembly for the same piece of code. You can generate a disassembly of your final file or any particular object files using the `avr-objdump` utility.

Cheers.

Comment: `volatile` is not used to guarantee atomicity of an update, as your `cli`/`sei` sequence seems to suggest. When sharing variables between ISRs and non-ISR code, the programmer has to ensure that no race conditions ensue. Adding `volatile` is not sufficient IMHO.

Comment: As a matter of fact, it is in this case. Refer to [this link](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_volatile) for details.

Comment: Your link shows an example where `flag`is a `uint8_t` and probably the processor/compiler used will guarantee that writes to a `uint8_t` are always atomic (as is customary). `volatile` just ensures that the `while`-loop can terminate at some point, re-reading `flag` on every iteration. If `flag` had been a `uint64_t`, the `volatile` would not have been sufficient by itself in most/all environments.

Comment: I would think another scenario where `volatile` would be important on a register-allocated variable would be in situations where a variable is read multiple times and where, if all reads were guaranteed to yield the same result, they could be replaced with a single read and some other operation (e.g. if `x+=reg;` is executed 16 times, substitute `x+=(reg<4);`.  Only if `reg` is volatile would that be forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

Reserving a register for one variable for a complete compilation unit is probably too restrictive for a compiler's code generator.  That is, every C routine would have to NOT use that register.

How do you guarantee that other called routines do NOT use that register once your code goes out of scope?  Even stuff like serial i/o routines would have to NOT use that reserved register.  Compilers do NOT recompile their run-time libraries based on a data definition in a user program.

Is your application really so time sensitive that the extra delay for bringing memory up from L2 or L3 can be detected?  If so, then your ISR might be running so frequently that the required memory location is always available (i.e. it doesn't get paged back down thru the cache) and thus does NOT hit a memory barrier (I assume by memory barrier you are referring to how memory in a cpu really operates, through caching, etc.).  But for this to really be true the up would have to have a fairly large L1 cache and the ISR would have to run at a very high frequency.

Finally, sometimes an application's requirements make it necessary to code it in ASM in which case you can do exactly what you are requesting!

Comment: The documentation I linked to described the issues relating to permanent register reservation, and it's a common idiom in embedded programming. Library routines are expected to use a certain register range (`r8` to `r15` on the AVR), and not modify others (`r2` to `r7`). The standard `avr-libc` library does in fact conform to this practice. The issue here isn't time but power ; I can put the controller back to sleep in about 10 instructions on the usual code path, but a load/store adds several more. The AVR has no cache, and while I'm aware that I can use `asm`, this *should* work.

Comment: Is the power consumed by several more instructions really that significant?  If so, then why are you using a compiled language?

Comment: Only during this particular loop, since I'm literally just decrementing a single byte counter, checking if zero, and going back to sleep, so the rest of the program is in C++. I have just been discovering this afternoon how impressively stupid GCC's assembly output is anyway, so I may be rewriting the ISR by hand, but it's going to be a pain to get communication between my setup routines and the ISR working, and according to C99, this *should* work.

Comment: @chrylis consider the amount of time the cpu is awake versus the interval that it is sleeping.  Usually, the wake time is a small fraction of the overall sleep time.  In this case probably 32ms interval and a few micro-seconds of wake time, thus the power usage is minimal.  To really save power consider powering down various components of the AVR and run with a minimal functioning cpu (if not already doing this).  An "out-of-the-box" solution might be in the hardware like using a larger battery, etc. (I'm really NOT trying to be sarcastic, it's just easy to focus on one solution to a problem).

Comment: Oh, for now I'm going to do just that and say "screw the ISR overhead" (I'd already put it in its own file), and if I do rework it I'll do it in straight assembly (GCC decrements a register variable by pushing another register, loading into it, performing a subtract immediate, loading back, and popping, instead of, say, `DEC`), but this is a construct that's legal and semantically meaningful, and I was hoping someone had an idea why GCC takes its ball home.

Comment: @chrylis, because its their ball!, but if you had to write a compiler you would end-up doing pretty much what they are doing in order to generate code that works in all possible cases.

Comment: While I'm not a compilers guy, I'm skeptical of that. In particular, unhelpful comments I've seen on the mailing list about this issue suggest that it may simply be because they took a shortcut in their internal data structures and belatedly realized that they threw out the `volatile` flag for `register` variables before they got to the optimizer, and it's easier to be non-compliant than to fix the hack. (And if you meant the assembly nonsense... there's just no excuse for it; the whole point of `register` is not to have to move it around for a trivial decrement and compare.)

Comment: (Oh, and FWIW regarding your original answer: I disassembled my entire image and checked, and the register reservation is in fact performed properly. GCC just then proceeds to perform stupid operations on it.)